# Create function to make SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, r

Eventually, I'm trying to create a reactive SQL query using shiny, but I'm having a little trouble with static inputs.  I have a basic function defined as follows, with a previous simpler version (only one input) that works just fine:

```
selectWhereIn <- function(col0,col1,group)
{
  myconn <- odbcConnect("WMT_Data")
  data <- sqlQuery(myconn, paste0("SELECT ",col0," FROM dbo.StoreInfo WHERE ",col1," in ('",group,"') ORDER BY ",col0))
  close(myconn)

  return(levels(data[,1]))
}
```

If I manually specify the three inputs and then run the query outside of a function, everything is fine, something like:

```
col0="hdd"
col1="WMTZone"
group="arid"

myconn <- odbcConnect("WMT_Data")
data <- sqlQuery(myconn, paste0("SELECT ",col0," FROM dbo.StoreInfo WHERE ",col1," in ('",group,"') ORDER BY ",col0))
close(myconn)
```

But when I try to run it outside of this file, I just get NULL returned, as such:

```
source("wmt_functions.r")
selectWhereIn("hdd","WMTZone","arid")
```

Like I said, I have this working with a much simpler SQL query, so I'm sure this is just something silly.  What am I missing?

Thanks
Ben

Comment: So basically you are trying to call function `selectWhereIn("hdd","WMTZone","arid")` and passing these 3 parameters and not getting expected output!

Comment: Yes - was that a question or a comment?  And it's not that I'm not getting the expected output, it's that I'm getting "NULL", but when I run all the code within the function, or run the function with only one input (hard coding the other two in the SQL query), it works fine.

Comment: The question was not very clear!
Did you try to print your query ?

Comment: Yes, and tested it directly in SQL Server which worked fine.  And as I said above in the second code chunk, the query also works from R.  I think it has something to do with the function definition or call that is causing me issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it - it was just a silly mistake.  IN the function

```
return(levels(data[,1]))
```

should have just been

```
return(levels(data[,1]))
```

Levels was required earlier for some reason, but is no longer, and since there were no levels, I was getting a NULL.